# pipenv install error : cannot import name 'project' from 'pipenv.core'

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

I'm trying to run a Python script on Pycharm but when I try to do `pipenv install`, I get this error `cannot import name 'project' from 'pipenv.core'`

I have :  `pipenv 2018.11.26` and `Python 3.7`

Does anyone know how to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was enough to upgrade `pipenv` with

```sh
pip install -U pipenv
```

You may need to add `--user` flag if you have `pipenv` installed per user.